# Checking existence of container with SAS token

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using SAS token to initialize CloudBlobContainer as shown below.

```
  CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasToken));
```

Now initialization is success with the sasToken, but when I am using `blobContainer.Exists()` I am getting **403 forbidden** exception.

Is there any way to check the validity of token?

Currently I am trying to add data to the container. If it raises an exception I am assuming it to be wrong SAS url.

I have only Write access for the container.

Thanks.

Comment: You're already doing the right thing. Since the SAS only has Write permission, you can only validate it by writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now initialization is success with the sasToken, but when I am using blobContainer.Exists() I am getting 403 forbidden exception.
>   Is there any way to check the validity of token?

The `blobContainer.Exists()` need a Read permission.  And only the Account SAS could operate the container service layer. The Service SAS haven't this permission. You could read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

I have created  two simple demos which the SAS token includes Write and Read permissions. It works fine. You could refer to my code:

For **Sevice SAS**, I set the Write and Read permissions for container. But you haven’t the permission to get result about `blobContainer.Exists()`:

Code in Console:

```cs
class Program
{
    static CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("orders");
        string sasUri = GetContainerSasUri(container, null);  //create SAS for container by using storage account
        Console.WriteLine("SAS uri:" + sasUri);
        string containerSas = sasUri;
         UseContainerSAS(containerSas);

    }
    static void UseContainerSAS(string sas)
    {
        //Try performing container operations with the SAS provided.
        //Return a reference to the container using the SAS URI.
        CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sas));//container use SAS
        //1. test Read permissions
        try
        {
            bool b = container.Exists();
            Console.WriteLine("container exists: " + b);
        }catch(StorageException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Read permission in Container: " + e.Message);
        }
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("peter.txt"); //blob named peter
        //2. test Write permission 
        try
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlobWrite = container.GetBlockBlobReference("peter.txt"); //blob named peter2
            // Save blob contents to a file.
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\log.txt"))
            {
                blockBlobWrite.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
                Console.WriteLine("Write content to blob successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write permission: " + e.Message);
        };
        //3. test Delete permission
        try
        {
            blockBlob.Delete();
            Console.WriteLine("Delete blob successfully.");
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete permission:" + e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    //The method to create sas token for container
    private static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container, string storedPolicyName = null)
    {
        string sasContainerToken;

        // If no stored policy is specified, create a new access policy and define its constraints.
        if (storedPolicyName == null)
        {              
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(24), //set 24min
                //set permissions for container
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            };
            // Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
            sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocPolicy, null);
            Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob container (ad hoc): {0}", sasContainerToken);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, storedPolicyName);
            Console.WriteLine("SAS for blob container (stored access policy): {0}", sasContainerToken);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        // Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
        return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
    }
}
```

The result about Service SAS:
[image]

**For account SAS**,you have the permissions to get result about `container.Exists()`.

Get Account SAS: Azure portal>storage account>settings>SAS>choose read and write permissions>Generate SAS>Copy blob service SAS url.

The code in Console:

```cs
string accountSasToken = "blob service SAS url";
StorageCredentials accountSAS = new StorageCredentials(accountSasToken);
CloudStorageAccount accountWithSAS = new CloudStorageAccount(accountSAS, " storage account name", endpointSuffix:null, useHttps: true);
CloudBlobClient client = accountWithSAS.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("orders");
try
{
    bool b = container.Exists();
    Console.WriteLine("container exists: " + b);
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Read permission in Container: " + e.Message);
}
try
{
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlobWrite = container.GetBlockBlobReference("peter.txt"); //blob named peter2
    // Save blob contents to a file.
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\log.txt"))
    {
        blockBlobWrite.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
        Console.WriteLine("Write content to blob successfully");
    }
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write permission: " + e.Message);
}
```

The result about Account SAS:
[image]